# Force links within iframe to open in iframe

Tags: angularjs

Hello everyone I am very new to Angularjs, I have been trying to convert a simple jQuery script to angular but seem pretty impossible. I need you help pls find my code below

```
---- HTML CODE ----
<iframe name="web" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

And my jQuery

```
---- JQUERY ----
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').attr('target', 'web');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the angularjs way is to deal with target, but a plain JavaScript-way to set it is

```
 var i,a=document.getElementsByTagName('a'),n=a.length;
 for (i=0;i<n;i++) a[i].setAttribute('target','web')
```

(Of course, this needs to be done in a section that is fired, once the DOM is readily loaded.)

Answer (score 4):

Just declare your anchors with the `target` attribute already set:

```
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="web">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

---

If you're dead-set on having this attribute added after-the-fact (presumably because you want to bypass any validation noise complaining about `target`) you'd do so using a Directive:

**Markup**

```
<a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" my-target="web">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('whatever', []).directive('myTarget', function() {
    return {
        link: function( scope, el, attrs ) {
            el.attr('target', attrs.myTarget);
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hN2KI0UAjFvqH9zqb1Oh?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Andre'.. But i am still experiencing the same problem.. whenever a link is being clicked within the iframe, it opens up the safari browser. I need the iframe to contain the link within itself as the parent frame.

Comment: This comment contradicts your sample code. If you have links within your `<iframe>` that you'd like to have opened inside the `<iframe>` then don't set `target` at all.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Andre', then issue is.. I am loading a foreign page i.e "http://knowhow.com". when a link is being touched on the ipad, safari loads in on the browse. I was reading randomly on the internet and came across someone mentioned "ChildBrowser" for phoneGap. I'm with this you will understand better.. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

```
---- HTML ----
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <a href="http://www.lipsum.com/" target="web">Lorem Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What relevance does the `ng-controller` assignment have with the OP's question?